# CloudFormation condition for stack policy

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I there a way to create a condition for stack policy?

Given the simple CF template from AWS documentation:

```
{
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Deny",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "LogicalResourceId/ProductionDatabase"
    },
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

where am I supposed to put the following condition:

```
"Condition" : "CreateProdResources"
```

Comment: This page (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition) shows you how to specify conditions in an IAM policy. And here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html) is an S3 example.

Comment: Thanks. so the answer is in each individual statement i can put a condition.

Comment: Is that a statement or a question? IAM policies can have one or more statements. Each statement grants permissions to a different set of resources or grants permissions under a specific condition. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies-basic-structure for more detail on policy structure. Also, you can play with the IAM Policy Simulator to test things.

Answer (score 9):

There are actually *three* different, *mutually-incompatible* types of `Condition` you need to distinguish:

1. [CloudFormation Resource Conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html). Defined by an item in the `Conditions` section of a stack template and a corresponding `Condition` key in a Resource referencing the condition.
2. [IAM Policy `Condition`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition) element/block. Allows any IAM policy to further restrict permissions based on the specified condition.
3. [CloudFormation Stack Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html) `Condition` element. Allows a stack policy only to apply to specific types of Resources.

You cannot add #1-type CloudFormation Resource Conditions (such as `CreateProdResources`, which in stack template [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html#d0e19114) conditionally creates a resource based on the value of an input Parameter) to a Stack Policy. These can only be defined in your template.

Neither can you use #2-type IAM Policy Conditions in a Stack Policy; however, you can use IAM policies as a separate layer of security for limiting access to creating/updating/deleting resources from CloudFormation. See [AWS CloudFormation Security Best Practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-cloudformation-security-best-practices/) blog post for more detail on how to use IAM Policies along with Stack Policies for even greater security.

You can only add a #3-type Condition to a CloudFormation Stack Policy, to have the particular Action apply only to the resource types specified by the Condition. For example, to set a Stack Policy disallowing updates to any `AWS::EC2::Instance` or `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` resources:

```
{
  "Statement" : [
  {
    "Effect" : "Deny",
    "Principal" : "*",
    "Action" : "Update:*",
    "Resource" : "*",
    "Condition" : {
      "StringEquals" : {
        "ResourceType" : ["AWS::EC2::Instance", "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : "*",
    "Action" : "Update:*",
    "Resource" : "*"
  }
  ]
}
```